# Access return value of JQuery/AJAX on a different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I want to access the returned boolean of my function on another function.

```
$('.asset_edit').change(function(){
        var asset_id=$(this).attr('id');
        var asset=$("#"+asset_id).val();

        var dataString = "device="+device+"&asset="+asset;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('c_device/check_assetCode'); ?>",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                if(html)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there a way where I could access the "return true or return false" on my 
**$(".edit_tr").click(function()** function?

In Javascript you just call the certain function name but in jQuery, I have no idea how to.

Comment: Ah, the question asked 100 times a day. It can not be done because the Ajax call you are using is asynchronous.

Comment: You can change a variable asynchronously, the variable will be changed when the success event is fired.

Comment: You can see my answer and example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global variable;

```
var global_status;
$('.asset_edit').change(function(){
        var asset_id=$(this).attr('id');
        var asset=$("#"+asset_id).val();

        var dataString = "device="+device+"&asset="+asset;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('c_device/check_assetCode'); ?>",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                if(html) {
                   global_status="true";
                   return true;
                }
                else {
                    global_status="false";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });

$(".edit_tr").click(function() {
   alert(global_status);
})
```

Here is a working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/vWkjr/1/**

While testing, first click edit and see undefined, and then select value from selectbox and click edit.

Comment: But first, you need to trigger change event. First trigger that and global_status will be set.

Comment: This is the right way to go, but I would recommend some validation in the click event. Perhaps check if the value is set, and if not alert "waiting for ajax to complete, try again later"

Comment: @epascarello: I upvoted, and nobody is suggesting you can return a value to the original calling function. This solution provides a method to set a result value that can be accessed from another method - which is what is being asked

Comment: @Mel Sy Gallosa I have added js fiddle for example

Answer (score 1):

insted of using return value you can add a class specifying html or not to the element it self. or you can declare a global variable and assign the value to it.

```
$('.asset_edit').change(function(){
    var asset_id=$(this).attr('id');
    var asset=$("#"+asset_id).val();

    var dataString = "device="+device+"&asset="+asset;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('c_device/check_assetCode'); ?>",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            if(html)
                $(this).addClass('ishtml');
            else
                $(this).addClass('nothtml');
        }
    });
});
```

And this class can be accessed with in other functions. like

```
function somefunction(){
    if($('.asset_edit .ishtml ').length){
          //true then do something
      }else{
          //false then do something
      }
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provided an example solution along with your theory. That would make for a more complete and useful answer